# Remove TeleNav GPS app from myTouch 4G Slide

Tags: applications, root-access, bloatware

After accepting a system update, I found that T-Mobile installed *TeleNav GPS* on my phone. Tech tier support tells me there is no way to remove it since it is installed as a "system level" app or something.

I'd really like to remove it, because it interferes with the default Google Navigation app, coming up no matter how many times I set the defaults.

I planned to root the phone, following the instructions on [rootzwiki](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/HTC_myTouch_4G_Slide), but after running Revolutionary I got this message:

> Your device: doubleshot, with HBOOT 1.45.0013 is not supported at this time

I've read elsewhere I can unlock my bootloader with [software from HTC](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/), but that this will completely format the phone, erasing all personal data, installed apps, and messages.

Do I have any other options to remove this hostile GPS application?

Comment: On rooting this device, also take a look at [Working root method for myTouch 4G Slide?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24882/16575) (I know it's your own question, axiomx11 -- this is meant as a reference for others stumbling upon this page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an application called [Root Uninstaller Pro 2.7](http://www.mobiles24.com/downloads/s/552004-m1439-root_uninstaller_pro), with the sole purpose of allowing users uninstall either SYSTEM or REGULAR applications.

To download it to your phone via WAP:

1. Visit http://wap.mobiles24.com on your wap enabled handset
2. Select Download by ID and enter **552004**
3. Click Download Item

---

**Other links:**

[Root Uninstaller Pro 2.7 Android App Apk](http://androidapk-app.blogspot.pt/2012/03/root-uninstaller-pro-27-android-app-apk.html)

[Google Play :: Root Uninstaller Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.pro&hl=pt_PT) *(small price)*

Comment: Appreciate the links, but it appears this app only works if you already have root, which I don't.

Comment: If you overcome the issue of your personal data, by performing a backup, a world of solutions should present themselves :) _(I've got many solutions, but for your device they require the wipe-clean process)_

Comment: Ok, if that is what I have to do, I will do it then.  Thanks.

Comment: Another user here helped me [get root](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24882/working-root-method-for-mytouch-4g-slide), and I was able to use the uninstaller program you suggested. TeleNav is gone now, thanks!